# insert on synapse DW in ssms

Tags: sql, ssms, azure-synapse

simple insert code but i keep getting syntax errors the values lines have a value for each column in the table, it only has 3 columns, i've tried removing the comma, tried using semi colon tried nothing after closing parent, tried explicitly stating column name before values nothing works on this simple bit of code

[image: insert statement syntax error]

Answer (score 7):

Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly known as Azure SQL Data Warehouse) does not support the `INSERT ... VALUES` clause [for more than a single row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Simply convert these into a `SELECT` with `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.countryCurrency 
          SELECT 'Afganistan', 'Afghani', 'AFN'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Aland Islands', 'Euro', 'EUR'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Albania', 'Lek', 'ALL'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Algeria', 'Algerian Dinar', 'DZD'
UNION ALL SELECT 'American Samoa', 'US Dollar', 'USD'
-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server table value constructor is not supported in Azure Synapse, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql.