# SQL Query doesn't work in Azure SQL Data Warehouse (Synapse) why not?

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have an SQL query that works in an on-premise SQL Database, but when I try to execute it on an Azure SQL Data Warehouse, I get an error.
Does anyone know another way of writing this SQL Query so that it will work in Azure DW?

SQL Query is:

```
SELECT MAX(Dates) MostRecentDate FROM (VALUES('2020-01-01'), ('2021-01-01')) AS t(Dates)
```

Azure DW Error is:

Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 1, column: 39: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Here is the full SQL Query (real table names have been removed)

```
SELECT t1.reference, dd.closest_date, d1.date_one, d2.date_two, d3.date_three
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2 ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 AS t3 ON t1.table3_id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.table4 AS t4 ON t3.table4_id = t4.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.table5 AS t5 ON t4.table5_id = t5.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.table6 AS t6 ON t5.table6_id = t6.id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t3.outcome IS NULL THEN '5000-01-01' ELSE ISNULL(t3.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') END AS date_one) AS d1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(t2.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') AS date_two) AS d2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(t6.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') AS date_three) AS d3
/*the below works in normal SQL, but doesn't work in Azure SQL!!!*/
--  OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(Dates) closest_date FROM (VALUES(d1.date_one),(d2.date_two),(d3.date_three)) AS t(Dates)) AS dd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is nice but is not fully supported in Azure Synapse Analytics as per the documentation, ie Synapse is absent in the **Applies to** list at the top of the linked doc.    `VALUES` is supported for single rows as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349792/insert-on-synapse-dw-in-ssms), but the easiest fix for your example is to simply rewrite as a simple `UNION ALL` statement, eg

```
SELECT t1.reference, dd.closest_date, d1.date_one, d2.date_two, d3.date_three
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2 ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 AS t3 ON t1.table3_id = t3.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table4 AS t4 ON t3.table4_id = t4.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table5 AS t5 ON t4.table5_id = t5.id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table6 AS t6 ON t5.table6_id = t6.id
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t3.outcome IS NULL THEN '5000-01-01' ELSE ISNULL(t3.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') END AS date_one) AS d1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(t2.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') AS date_two) AS d2
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(t6.outcome_date,'5000-01-01') AS date_three) AS d3

/*the below works in normal SQL, but doesn't work in Azure Synapse*/
    --OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(Dates) closest_date FROM (VALUES(d1.date_one),(d2.date_two),(d3.date_three)) AS t(Dates)) AS dd
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(Dates) closest_date FROM ( SELECT d1.date_one UNION ALL SELECT d2.date_two UNION ALL SELECT d3.date_three) AS t(Dates)) AS dd
```

It's just syntactic sugar really.  They are all set operations at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this

```
 select max(t.dates)from
  (
      select '2020-01-01'as dates
        union all
      select '2021-01-01'
  )as t
```

Comment: I'm not sure that approach would work well. The query I provided was the simplest form of what I'm trying to achieve.  What I'm trying to do is pull through the max date from 3 different columns (with a variety of dates) from different tables, for every row in the dataset.  I will update my question with the full query for better clarity - as you will see I have to join to quite a few tables to pull through the date columns I need.

Comment: if I understand you in the right way, you can use CASE to find a max date between three of them

Comment: All you really have to do is replace `VALUES(d1.date_one),(d2.date_two),(d3.date_three)` with `SELECT d1.date_one UNION ALL SELECT d2.date_two UNION ALL SELECT d3.date_three` - should work.